# Find the ratio of AM:MO

Tags: triangles, median

In a $∆ABC$, $BD$ and $CE$ are two medians which intersect each other at ‘$O$’. $AO$ intersects the line $ED$ at $M$. Find the ratio of $AM: MO$ $?$

Comment: Please provide, at least, the figure. Moreover, note that we don't solve the homework, so please share your first step, it maybe wrong, but don't hesitate.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it by the method of vectors would be easiest I think. Consider a triangle $ABC$.

Take point $B$ to be origin, $A$ to be pointed by **a** and $C$ by **c**,
now $O$ is centroid(point of intersection of medians) hence is pointed by $($**a**$+$**b**$+$**c**$)/3$ here, $O\equiv($**a**$+$**c**$)/3$.

[image]

So the vector corresponding to M can be calculated by considering the point $M$ divides $AO$ in ratio $k:1$ $(=AM:MO)$ and segment $ED$ in ratio $h:1$ $(=EM:MD)$. Calculating the vector corresponding to M using the two ratios gives two vectors(eg. finding $M$ from $h$:- $ M\equiv$ {( $h$$($**a**$+$**c**$)/2$ + **a**$/2$)}{$h+1$}which are equal as they point to the same point, and comparing the coefficients of **a** and **c** in them, gives the values of $h$ and $k$. Hence the answer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

$AO$ is the third median, and let it intersect $BC $ at $N $. Now, let us denote $AN=a $. We know $AO=\frac {2}{3}a $ ($O$ - barycenter) and $AM=\frac {1}{2}a $ (from the homothety with the center in $A $ and coefficient $\frac {1}{2}$). Thus, $MO=\frac {1}{6}a $ and $AM:MO=\frac {1}{2}a : \frac {1}{6}a = 3:1$.

Comment: Please  explain a bit on AM=a/2 . How it came?

Comment: The homothety with the center in $A$ and coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$ will map $B$ into $E$, $C$ into $D$ and $N$ (the intersection of $AO$ with $BC$) into $M$ (the intersection of $AO$ with $ED$). Thus $AM=\frac{1}{2}AN=\frac{1}{2}a$.